# How to put comma separator for 1000 in $ amount in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I have created the report to show the amount in $ using data table in BI Publisher. It shows full amount as $ 265432. But I want to show $ 2,65,432. How to put comma separator in $ amount?

Answer (score 0):

When editing your layout, you have a tab called Data Formatting in the top bar. 
There you can choose your formatting preference. If that does not bring you enough flexibility, you can enhance the formatting options on the left bar, under Properties / Data Formatting